# slim framework Method notFound is not a valid method

Tags: php, api, slim

I am creating an api using the Slim framework for the first time.

I want to return a specific response if url not found.

I use `notFound` function of Slim framework as follows:

```
$app->notFound(function () use ($app) {
    $res = array("msg"=>"page not found");
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($res));
    return $response;
});
```

but when I add this line of code in my php page it shows me following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Method notFound is not a valid method' in C:\wamp\www\api\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php on line 129
>
> BadMethodCallException: Method notFound is not a valid method in C:\wamp\www\api\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php on line 129

Comment: Wrong version of Slim m8. You have Slim 3 installed.

Comment: So is this not work with slim 3?

Comment: No it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are using Slim 3 with some code from Slim 2.
In 3 you can do it by adding a handler in the container ([mode details here](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/10851-how-to-add-404-template-in-slim-3)) or by adding a middleware:
**Edit** - as @geggleto points out, I forgot to mention that for the code below you should also set `$settings['determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware'] = true`

```
/**
 * check if route exists
 */
$middleware = function (Request $request, Response $response, $next) {

    if (!$request->getAttribute('route')) {
        $res = array("msg"=>"page not found");
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($res));
        return $response;
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
};
$app->add($middleware);
```

Comment: This is missing some pretty critical details.... like the slim option for determinRouteBeforeDispatch